# Dev mode and "Extended debugging information on a response page in a case of a 5** server error"

Tags: ktor

What is the "Extended debugging information on a response page in a case of a 5** server error." described in the doc: https://ktor.io/docs/development-mode.html ?

Whether I'm in dev mode or not, exception only display an empty page with a 500 Internal Error. I know have access to the stacktrace using StatusPage.exception but what the point of the developpement mode ?

Comment: Thought I'd check this as well as I was curious. Finding the exact same thing, when I both respond with `call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)` or just `throw IllegalArgumentException()` I just get a white page

Comment: I've created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2684 to address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the solution using [StatusPages](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html#exceptions):

```kotlin
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
            if (this@configureRouting.developmentMode) {
                this@configureRouting.log.error(cause.message, cause)
            }

            call.respondText(text = "500: $cause" , status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```